# Using order(colSums()) in R

Tags: r, sorting, na

I have a data frame matrix in R that I wish to order by the sum of columns in a decreasing order. My data varies from values of +1 to -1. I have this code that does this pretty perfectly:

```
DF<-DF[, order(colSums(-DF))]
```

However, I do have some NA values spread out amongst the data (no single column or row is all NA so I cannot simply remove an entire column or row). I believe that the data is not being sorted properly, as columns that contain NAs are not sorted, and just placed behind the sorted columns.

Is there a way to order the data by sum of columns as above, but also allowing the sorting of columns with NAs as well?

Comment: Yeah, you can look at `order(c(1,NA,3,NA))` and see that the NAs are indeed assigned the last orders. To modify that, maybe use the `na.last` option mentioned in `?order`. `?colSums` shows that it has a `na.rm` option you might want. By the way, [dataframes] is the wrong tag for R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort "NA columns" behind "non-NA columns", but then you also want to sort the NA columns amongst themselves based on the result of `colSums()` applied to the non-NA cells within the NA columns. You can do this with an additional argument to `order()` to break ties in which you call `colSums()` with the additional argument `na.rm=TRUE`. Here's a demo with 4 columns total, 2 with NAs, 2 without:

```
set.seed(3L)
df <- setNames(rev(as.data.frame(replicate(4L,
     sample(c(seq(-1,1,0.5),NA),
            5L,rep=TRUE)))),letters[1:4])
df ## columns a and b are "NA columns", columns c and d are "non-NA columns"
##      a   b    c    d
## 1  1.0 0.5  0.5 -0.5
## 2 -1.0 0.5 -1.0  1.0
## 3  1.0 0.5 -0.5  0.0
## 4   NA 0.5  0.5 -0.5
## 5 -0.5  NA  0.5  0.5
colSums(-df) ## d should be moved before c, but can't tell yet about a and b
##    a    b    c    d
##   NA   NA  0.0 -0.5
colSums(-df,na.rm=TRUE) ## this can tiebreak a and b; b should be moved before a
##    a    b    c    d
## -0.5 -2.0  0.0 -0.5
df[,order(colSums(-df))] ## fails to order NA columns
##      d    c    a   b
## 1 -0.5  0.5  1.0 0.5
## 2  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.5
## 3  0.0 -0.5  1.0 0.5
## 4 -0.5  0.5   NA 0.5
## 5  0.5  0.5 -0.5  NA
df[,order(colSums(-df),colSums(-df,na.rm=TRUE))] ## tiebreaker orders NA columns properly
##      d    c   b    a
## 1 -0.5  0.5 0.5  1.0
## 2  1.0 -1.0 0.5 -1.0
## 3  0.0 -0.5 0.5  1.0
## 4 -0.5  0.5 0.5   NA
## 5  0.5  0.5  NA -0.5
```

---

Sorry, I misunderstood. Looks like this is what you're looking for:

```
df[,order(colSums(-df,na.rm=TRUE))]
##     b    a    d    c
## 1 0.5  1.0 -0.5  0.5
## 2 0.5 -1.0  1.0 -1.0
## 3 0.5  1.0  0.0 -0.5
## 4 0.5   NA -0.5  0.5
## 5  NA -0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Note that passing `na.rm=TRUE` is equivalent to treating NAs as zero, contrary to your proviso that regarding NAs as zero would mess up the sorting.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. Actually I wanted to sort the NA columns equally with the non-NA columns, I was saying above that the NA columns are placed behind the non-NA columns but that was not what I wanted! I believe that simply putting the argument "na.rm=T" in the colSums function is what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that the NAs being zero would not affect my sorting results after all =) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To allow for NA columns to be sorted equally with non-NA columns, use the "na.rm=TRUE" argument in the "colSums" function. This will override the original ordering of colSums where the NA columns are left unsorted behind the sorted columns. The final code is:

```
DF<-DF[, order(colSums(-DF, na.rm=T))]
```